# STL Vector sort

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct point{
    int index;
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

compare on bases of x and breaking ties on bases of y !!

```
bool comp1(const point& p1,const point& p2){
    if(p1.x<p2.x)
        return true;
    if(p1.x==p2.x){
        if(p1.y<p2.y)
            return true;
    return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

compare on bases of y and breaking ties on bases of x !!

```
bool comp2(const point &p1,const point &p2){
    if(p1.y<p2.y)
        return true;
    if(p1.y==p2.y){
        if(p1.x<p2.x)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
        int n;
        vector<point> px,py;
        cin>>n;
        point p;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>p.x>>p.y;
            p.index = i+1;
            px.push_back(p);
            py.push_back(p);

        }

        sort(px.begin(),px.end(),comp1);
        sort(py.begin(),py.end(),comp2);

        vector<point>::iterator it;
        for(it=px.begin();it!=px.end();it++)
            cout<<it->x<<" "<<it->y<<"\t";
        cout<<endl;

        for(it=py.begin();it!=py.end();it++)
            cout<<it->x<<" "<<it->y<<"\t   ";
        cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The Above code is producing ambiguous result .I am trying to sort points on bases of increasing x and than increasing y and vice-versa .

Comment: From your code its not obvious what you want to do with `px` and `py`. Please define clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I trying to sort points in 2D space in increasing order of x and than y
e.g  (2,0) (1,1) (1,0)

sorted (1,0) (1,1) (2,0)

Comment: If you have a problem reading data, you should ask a question about doing I/O correctly rather than ask a question about sorting vectors.

Comment: Just read this again - you shouldn't be doing two sorts -- the second sort will just replace the first.  Just do the sort with comp1 using the `pair` method I mention below - that will sort first by x and then by y

Comment: Work as (I) expected [Demo](https://ideone.com/9PpUoa). Unclear what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could really simplify the logic by using `std::pair()`'s built-in `operator<`, which does a lexicographic compare:

```
bool comp1(const point& p1,const point& p2){
  return std::make_pair(p1.x, p1.y) < std::make_pair(p2.x, p2.y);
}
// swap x and y order for comp2
bool comp2(const point& p1,const point& p2){
  return std::make_pair(p1.y, p1.x) < std::make_pair(p2.y, p2.x);
}
```

Comment: what if p1.x==p2.x I need to sort than in increasing order of y !!

Comment: std::pair's comparison does that for you -- see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp :  "Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically, that is, compares the first elements and only if they are equivalent, compares the second elements."

Comment: `std::tie` is an other option.

Comment: That's true. Personally though I find that form quite error-prone and it doesn't scale well to more than 2 arguments. +1 for the `tie` suggestion though -- I've been using that myself recently